# How I can avoid duplicate in combo boxes in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

How can I avoid duplicate in combo boxes?

I have 3 combo boxes that I want the user can Either add or select from the existing value but when I select one of the existing item it duplicate the item

```
With something
   .DataSource = empBindingsource 
   .DisplayMember = "Employer_Name" 
   .ValueMember = "Employer_ID" 
   .DataBindings.Add("selectedValue", job_VacanciesBindingsource, "Employer_ID", False, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnValidation) 
End With 

With cboDesc 
   .DataSource = descDataset.Tables("Job_Vacancies").Copy 
   .DisplayMember = "Job_Description" ' 
   .ValueMember = "Job_ID" 
   .DataBindings.Add("text", job_VacanciesBindingsource, "Job_Description", False, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnValidation) 
End With
```

Comment: Show us some code so that we know what you are doing.

Comment: Don't put one in there basically.

Comment: .DataSource = empBindingsource
            .DisplayMember = "Employer_Name"
            .ValueMember = "Employer_ID"
            .DataBindings.Add("selectedValue", job_VacanciesBindingsource, "Employer_ID", False, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnValidation)
        End With

        With cboDesc

            .DataSource = descDataset.Tables("Job_Vacancies").Copy
            .DisplayMember = "Job_Description"
            ' .ValueMember = "Job_ID"
            .DataBindings.Add("text", job_VacanciesBindingsource, "Job_Description", False, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnValidation)
        End With

Comment: I have 3 combo boxes that I want the user can Either add or select from the existing value but when I select one of the existing item it duplicate the item.

Comment: hi Tony , could you show me where exactly is the one?

Comment: @Mahi, you should always put code in your question, not in the comments.  I moved it for you so you can see what style people expect here on SO.  Good luck!

Comment: @Mahi How are you adding the contents in combo boxes? Are you adding existing + new or just the new item. If you are adding existing + new items in the combo box you need to clear the items in the combo box.

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't very clear but could you try:

```
.DataSource = descDataset.Tables("Job_Vacancies").Copy.Distinct()
```